# How to make the Asus PCE-N53 wifi card work with Ubuntu 16?

Tags: drivers, wireless, asus

I really need wifi as Ethernet is not much of an option for me. I just switched to Ubuntu and have not used it before. (Switched from Windows) if someone could please tell me how to get it to work with Ubuntu 16.04 it would be really appreciated. I have looked around online and I attempted to install it but I could no get it to work. Thank you

Comment: Ubuntu Xenial (aka 16.04) should pick up any _wifi network_ around _automatically_, is it not picking it up ? __icon is in the top right corner of your desktop__

Comment: Yes, it's not picking up anything. When I click the wifi button it says wired connection and that is all, none of my home networks are there

Comment: Check in `/var/lib/NetworkManager.state` to see if `WirelessEnabled=true`

Answer (score 5):

I have achieved some results right now. I have `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` and `Asus PCE-N53 card`.

I have built a driver, using instructions from here:

https://github.com/mareksuscak/asus-pce-n53-linux

I had to fix 2 compile errors, changed this

```
pci_read_config_word(((POS_COOKIE)pAd->OS_Cookie)->pci_dev, offset, &Configuration);
```

to this

```
pci_read_config_word(((POS_COOKIE)pAd->OS_Cookie)->pci_dev, offset, (u16*)&Configuration);
```

in 2 places of a file `rtmp_mcu.c`

After installing the driver, I run this command:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

I saw, that `RT5592 PCIe Wireless Network Adapter` was disabled.

I did this (`enp3s0` is a logical name from the previouse command)

```
sudo ifconfig enp3s0 up
```

So after that I could scan wifi with

```
sudo iwlist scan
```

There were WiFi spots in the result.

So, the final step is:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

I have all WiFi spots in the network connections.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I had been trying to get this driver to work on 16.04/kernel 4.10.0-37 for the last 4 hours haha

Comment: @cygnus_x1 You are welcome. The problem now is that the adapter disappears after some time (probably during some components update).

Comment: This helped. However I had problem compiling the driver. Well, it would compile but modprobe part did not work. So I had to compile it like this `make CC=/usr/bin/gcc-5` instead of just plain `make`

Answer (score 0):

why can't idiot developers include patches in the original distribution?
why do I need to be a linux guru to install it FIRST TIME with an already working wireless network?